# Does react native support Blob?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, blob

I am working on a react native project where i have to upload an image to my company specified cloud services (which i cant disclose here) which requires XMLHttpRequest Level 2, FileReader and Blob support.

```
var srcData = new Blob([base64Data], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

I have to use the above variable `srcData` in a service call as a parameter which will upload the file into the cloud and provide me a callback with its url. I use this URL to update user Object in my database.

But i was facing an issue with the keyword `Blob`. After spending some time investigating,  i figured out that upgrading to react native 0.54 version solved the issue with `Blob` keyword.

I am not able to understand where i am going wrong and does react native support Blob, XMLHttpRequest or fileReader?  Is there any way i can solve this issue?

Any lead would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -3):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)

```
var aBlob = new Blob( array[, options]);
```

where array is an Array of [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), [`ArrayBufferView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView), [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) or a mix of any of such objects.

`Base64` comprises of neither of the above, it just represents *binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation*.

Since you already have `base64`, therefore the best way to generate a `blob` from it, without including any external libraries would be

```
export const generateBlob = base64URL => fetch(base64URL)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(response => console.log('Your blob is' + response)
```

Comment: Okay i have perform those steps and converted the base64 data into blob. In order to make a service call, my cloud services use XMLHttpRequest. Does react native supports XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Blob exists, but via fetch in react native you get `res.blob is not a function`

Comment: fetch(base64URL)

is not working for android!